# symfony3 save object to mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony

I get a json object from the front-end application like this:

```
{
key1: 'value1'
key2: {
  key3: 'value3',
  key4: {
    key5: 'velue5'
}
}
}
```

in my form how can I tell symfony that key2 for instance is an object composed of multiple fields, I want something like this:

```
    $builder
        ->add('key1', Type\TextType::class)
        ->add('key2', Object, [
           'key3' => Type\TextType::class
    ]);
```